# When is end of life for dotnet framework 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have close to 30 apps running on .net framework 4.5.2

Can someone explain the following paragraph from Microsoft site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework) in simple terms

It says "Beginning with version 4.5.2 and later, .NET Framework is defined as a component of the Windows operating system (OS). Components receive the same support as their parent products, therefore, .NET Framework 4.5.2 and later follows the lifecycle policy of the underlying Windows OS on which it is installed.  "

If we keep upgrading our Windows server OS, will there ever be a need to upgrade the framework? I assume Microsoft will keep sending security patches for 4.5.2.

Comment: From the page you linked to: ".NET Framework 4.5.2: Support for .NET 4.5.2 follows the lifecycle policy of the parent OS. It is supported as a Windows component on the latest required operating system update for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1 Update, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2."

Comment: Hi @mason does this mean Microsoft wont support 4.5.2 apps beyond Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Why does this matter? Why don't you just update to the latest .NET 4.x?

Comment: in all real terms: it is already dead; if you aren't already making plans to migrate to .NET Core, *you probably want to do that*; if the question is purely "how long have we got to do that?" - then fine, but  the "will there ever be a need to upgrade the framework?" suggests that this is not your plan, in which case: your plan is a bad one, IMO

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### UPDATE

Microsoft just announced end-of-life for .NET 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1: April 26, 2022.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/

### Original Post

See this page for what OS versions are supported for each .NET version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements

From how I understand it, .NET 4.5.2 goes out of support when Windows 8.1 goes out of support, as it is the last Windows OS where .NET 4.5.2 is officially supported.

Therefore, .NET 4.5.2 goes out of support on January 10, 2023.